# Get live width and collapse an menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am in a difficult time for 2 days with a code for collapsing a menu . I'm trying really hard to realize what am i doing Wrong.

The problem with this code is that when you resize the browser it won't work again.

If someone could help me , i would appreciate it very much.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function jqUpdateSize(){
        // Get the dimensions of the viewport
        var width = $(window).width();

        if(width<=768){
            $('.toggle-nav-this-site').css("display","block");  

            $('.toggle-nav-this-site .button-this-tg').click( function(){
                $('.aside-menu > ul').toggle('showElem');
            });

        }else{
            $('.toggle-nav-this-site').css("display","none");   
            $('.aside-menu > ul').show();   
        }


        $('#jqWidth').html(width);      // Display the width
    };
    $(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);    // When the page first loads
    $(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);     // When the browser changes size


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used jQuery, but with plain JS you first have to add an EventListener:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', functionname);
```

This called function has to change all variables.

You can get the window-Size by: `window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth`